# ionic page transition event - similar to jquery pageshow event

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

What is the equivalent for handling page loading events in ionic framework? I want to add an event to track all page loads from my app with ionic framework. In jquerymobile, there are events like `pagebeforeshow`, `pageshow` etc., Is there any equivalent event in ionic?

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer here: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-detect-page-change-in-ionic/5181

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    ...
});
```